# LaTeX generated PDFs miss division lines when printed

Tags: pdf, printing

I regularly get sent LaTeX generated PDFs (university assignments) which contain mathematical equations.

Whenever I print these all the division lines (i.e. the middle of the fraction) are missing from the printed document.

My printer is an HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M277 but I have never had any other mis-printing issues, only from these LaTeX PDFs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly what programme are you using to print with? I've seen something similar (long time ago) with the Apple Preview programme as it filtered the PDF and poof the lines in fractions and sqrt were gone. So I'd start by testing the programmes you use to print.

Comment: The Firefox built-in PDF viewer pdf.js also used to have problems with rendering LaTeX generated PDFs which resulted in garbled output on the printer.

Comment: @HenriMenke as does SumatraPDF

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat Reader on a windows 10 laptop.